# Mod_rewrite: redirect to hash urls?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect common URLs to hash URLs, like this below,

```
http://localhost/mywebsite/estate/heritage/
```

to

```
http://localhost/mywebsite/#/estate/heritage/
```

I have this rewrite code in my .htaccess,

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$  #/$1/$2/  [R,L,NE]
```

But the result I get is,

```
http://localhost/C:/wamp/www/mywebsite/#/estate/heritage/
```

It has this extra bit `C:/wamp/www/` which I don't want.

How can I remove it or how not to print it in my rewrite code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place this rule in `/mysaite/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# set ENV variable BASE equal to current RewriteBase value dynamically
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ %{ENV:BASE}#/$1/$2/ [L,NC,NE,R=302]
```

Using `RewriteBase` is very important to fix your stated problem.

Comment: thanks. how can I make `RewriteBase /mysite/` dynamic instead of putting it in manually then?

Answer (score 1):

You need a complete new URL, like so:

```
RewriteRule ^/mywebsite/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$  /mywebsite/#/$1/$2/  [R,L,NE]
```